# Dynamic Tree control in Flex 3

Tags: flex3, tree

I am looking for sample code to create a dynamic Tree control in Flex using a Collection of objects obtained from the backend(Perl cgi).

So, initially the Tree will display the root nodes. Clicking root node, will invoke the data  for populating the child nodes (basically adding child nodes on demand). Clicking child nodes will  pull another collection  add child nodes of child node.

So, lets assume Initially the Tree will display -
Root1
Root2
Root3

Clicking Root1 will display something like this -

Root1
           Child 1
           Child 2
Root2
Root3

And Clicking Child1 will display -

Root1
          Child 1
                   Child1 of Child 1
                   Child2 of Child 1
          Child 2
Root2
Root3

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The [standard Flex tree control](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_8.html) does this.

You can use the [itemOpen event](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/dpcontrols_8.html#415295) to communicate with the back-end.